# breaking float value in char and transmit it on tcp and read using java program

Tags: java, c

I using this c code to convert and transmit float data form micro controller using TCP/IP. Here I break float in to four char value and this work well. But I need its equivalent java code to again get float value on server end.

I am new for java. so please help.

/********************************************************************************/

```
unsigned char outbox[5];

void breakDown(void)
{
  int index=0;
  float member=-600.231;    

  unsigned long d = *(unsigned long *)&member;
  outbox[0] = d & 0x00FF;
  outbox[1] = (d & 0xFF00) >> 8;
  outbox[2] = (d & 0xFF0000) >> 16;
  outbox[3] = (d & 0xFF000000) >> 24;

  }


  void buildUp(void) 
  {
   unsigned long d;
   unsigned index;

   d =  ((long)outbox[3] << 24);
   d|=  ((long)outbox[2] << 16);
   d|=  ((long)outbox[1] << 8);
   d|=  ((long)outbox[0]);

   float member = *(float *)&d;
   printf("Float output=%f\n\n",member);

   }
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow isn't a free code-conversion service. Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

java.io.DataInputStream.readFloat() which invokes java.lang.Float.intBitsToFloat(int bits), you may try it. (read the api doc first)

Answer (score 0):

Why are you trying to split the variable into different segments? Just send it as a string, then use JAVA function to convert it to the float variable.

```
String numberAsString = "153.25";
float number = Float.parseFloat(numberAsString);
```